# MySQL Trigger Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb

Running on MySQL 5.5.9 with InnoDB.

I created the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_Products_Insert
AFTER INSERT ON Products

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Products
SET current = 0
WHERE   id = new.id
    AND current = 1
    AND autonumber <> new.autonumber
END;
```

MySQLWorkbench shows a syntax error on the last line, and executing this throws the following error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 11

Where is my error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_Products_Insert AFTER INSERT ON Products
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE Products
        SET current = 0
        WHERE   id = new.id
            AND current = 1
            AND autonumber <> new.autonumber;
    END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: This works, but I have no clue why the `DELIMITER` stuff is necessary.

Comment: Because `BEGIN ... END` is a "body" of trigger. So, it is must be a part of current query. `;` is a delimeter by default, so when MySQL reaches it, it thinks that this is the end of query and cannot parse it. Also, you must put delimeters in "body" of trigger because it would be invalid in another way. So, to meet this requirements, we need to use two different delimeters in "body" of trigger and in query for itself. Sorry, my english is too bad to describe this not obvious thing better...

Comment: This better described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/begin-end.html (third paragraph, starts with "Use of multiple statements requires that a client is able")

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` before your `END` keyword:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_Products_Insert
AFTER INSERT ON Products

FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE Products
SET current = 0
WHERE   id = new.id
    AND current = 1
    AND autonumber <> new.autonumber;
END;
```

Comment: Doesn't work, gives errors on both the last and the second last line now.